# SUM of Column where Multiple Rows Have Same Value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the sum of a single column from all rows that share similar data. For example, given the following data:

```
|ppID | cID   | Count | NameSpace|
|-----|-------|-------|----------|
|586  | 18281 | 1     | LAB      |
|587  | 18269 | 1     | LAB      |
|588  | 18281 | 1     | LAB      |
|589  | 17823 | 1     | IPB      |
|590  | 18281 | 1     | LAB      |
|591  | 18256 | 1     | LAB      |
|592  | 18256 | 1     | LAB      |
|593  | 18269 | 1     | IPB      |
|-----|-------|-------|----------|
```

I'm hoping to get:

```
|ppID | cID   | Count | NameSpace|
|-----|-------|-------|----------|
|586  | 18281 | 3     | LAB      |
|587  | 18269 | 1     | LAB      |
|589  | 17823 | 1     | IPB      |
|591  | 18256 | 2     | LAB      |
|593  | 18269 | 1     | IPB      |
|-----|-------|-------|----------|
```

I've pieced together a couple of different things and come up with `

```
SELECT * FROM PopularPages 
WHERE cID IN (SELECT cID FROM PopularPages 
              GROUP BY cID 
              HAVING COUNT(cID) > 1) 
ORDER BY cID, Namespace
```

which will list out each of the rows but without counting up the sum of the `Count` column. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does the third row in the example output (ppID=588) have a Count of 1 and not 2? (I thought I understood what you wanted to accomplish, but that third row shows that I'm not understanding the logic.) And what happened to rows 590 and 592?

Comment: Is your count by cid and Namespace or just CID.  If just CID, which namespace should be displayed?

Comment: @spencer7593 It shouldn't be editing now.

Comment: Also... why is line 588 in your results... shouldn't it be part of the count for line 586? thus count of 3?

Comment: Holy balls @xQbert, are you just following up on what everyone else says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you want ?

```
SELECT
  MIN(ppID) as ppID,
  cID,
  SUM(`Count`) as COUNT,
  NameSpace
FROM PopularPages
GROUP BY cID
HAVING Count > 1;
```

Comment: May need to have namespace in group by as well; can't tell based on data/OP question though.  Also I don't think you want the having... the expected results show counts of 1.

Comment: yes , **GROUP BY cID** , NameSpace - so it is possible that you have more lines with the same cID and different namSpace. Also you can extend the query after the havin with **ORDER BY cID,Namespace DESC;*

Comment: I'm understanding how this statement produces the resultset specified by OP, except by accident. This result produced by this query seems significantly different from OP specification.

Comment: I think you're after this as the final version:     `SELECT
      MIN(ppID) as ppID,
      cID,
      SUM('Count') as Count,
      NameSpace
    FROM PopularPages
    GROUP BY cID, Namespace;` where ticks are really backticks

Comment: This is it, need to group by cID and Namespace, like your comment added. Thank you.